# How do I compare numbers using if and or statements in matlab?

Tags: matlab, comparison, logic

I want to return true if the element of an array `b=[1,2,3,4,5]` equals 1 or 2 or 5. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

There are different ways to do that:

- Test an individual element against one number

  `b(1) == 5`
- Test an individual element against several numbers, i.e. is the first element either 1 or 2 or 5?

  `b(1) == 1 || b(1) == 2 || b(1) == 5`

  `%# which is equivalent to`

  `any(b(1) == [1 2 5];`
- Test all (or many) elements against one number

  `b == 1; %# a vector with t/f for each element`
- Test all elements against several numbers

  `b == 1 | b == 2 | b == 5 %# note that I can't use the shortcut ||`

  `%# this is equivalent to`

  `ismember(b,[1 2 5])`

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple. To test equality of numbers you simply use the `==` operator.

```
if (b(1) == 5)
    %% first element of b is 5 
    %% now implement code you require
```

similarly you can test equality for any element in a matrix. To test for multiple values use the logical or operator `||` in conjunction with `==` for example

```
if (b(1) == 5 || b(1) == 2 || b(1) == 1)
    %% first element of b is 1,2 or 5 
    %% now implement code you require
```